# Can Mathematica show Hebrew,Arabic and Persian languages correctly?

Tags: natural-language

Right to left languages don't show correctly in Mathematica ,is there a way to type RTL languages without them being reversed?

Comment: As a side note think that Arabic has more problems in rendering on Mathematica than just the direction, also the complex layout seems to be missing, which is hardly a surprise if the direction is already wrong.